# How can we added a controller by using WF admin?

Tags: php, cakephp

My boss give me some assignment to find information "How to add a controller by using wildflower admin (dashboard)? and how can we manipulate it (wf admin)?". I've searched each with Google but it's too difficult to find it. Maybe I'm not so great to do the research job. So, please help me you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Wildflower is a CMS built on the CakePHP framework. A controller is a code construct used in the CakePHP framework. If I understand your question correctly, what your boss is asking for is some way to make the application write code into itself...

However, if I understand your boss' *intent* correctly, it sounds like he wants something like [Drupal's Content Construction Kit (CCK)](http://drupal.org/project/cck) in Wildflower which, as far as I know, doesn't exist.

CakePHP comes with a console app called "bake". You can quickly create "scaffolding" for a model by running some bake commands. In theory, you could write an extension for Wildflower that could send commands to bake to generate scaffolding for quick add/edit/delete interfaces for those models.... but they wouldn't integrate with the WF admin or WF in general.

With all the effort it would take to build an interface like that, you could just add the new models to the application yourself, or build a proper CCK-like extension for WF.